# delete everything including newline between two words

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

I have the following example

```
a = 'cloth <type> length \n
    short \n
    width \n
    </type> close'
```

want to change a to the following:

```
b = 'cloth close'
```

I tried re.sub with `re.DOTALL` expression, but it doesn't work

Comment: the "two words" are always the first and the last or they can be in any position into your original string?

Comment: Which expression did you use? How do you call it? What is not working? Your question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `\n` with space, split by white-space and take the first ad last element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to delete the content between **type** tags, you can try this:

```
b = a.gsub(/<type>[\w\s\t\n]+<\/type>/, '').gsub(/\s\s/, ' ')
```

It works with ruby

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you just wanted the first and last element of the list and the following works:

```
a = '''cloth <type> length \n
    short \n
    width \n
    </type> close'''
a_split = a.split()                        #Splits on whitespace into tokens
b = [a_split[0], a_split[len(a_split)-1]]  #Take the first and last token
```